# Django database query: how to get multiple objects by id?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I want to get a filtered object with several id's that I will specify:

```
TestQuestionBlok.objects.filter()
```

How to write this filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a list of the ids, like `[1, 4, 9]`, you can work with the [**`__in`** lookup <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#in):

```
TestQuestionBlok.objects.filter(pk__in=[1, 4, 9])
```

Given these ids exist (in the database), these will be in the queryset. So it will return *at most* three items here with the same query.